What is the relationship between RMS level and amplitude?
I have an Android recorder project, and I'm trying to implement a waveform display for recording and playing audio.
During recording, I chose to use mediaRecorder.maxAmplitude to get the data I need to draw the waveform.
During audio playback (importing other audio from storage, so I can't use the above method), I used ffprobe -v error -f lavfi -i amovie=audioFile,asetnsamples=44100,astats=metadata=1:reset=1 -show_entries frame_tags=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level -of csv=p=0 to get the data. However, their outputs look very different.
For the same audio:
The amplitude data looks like this:
0
351
650
31987
402
443
674
432
774
1156
32139
565
532
511
355
366
628
25996
610
700
423
1317
1241
621
1078
1994
1068
1549
0

The RMS level data looks like this:
-63.081060
-47.268557
-46.641208
-29.585361
-47.808792
-46.119954
-45.888205
-46.613955
-39.633273
-29.618461
-48.102711
-45.607349
-47.897675
-48.915841
-50.470556
-51.066509
-45.216680
-29.337245
-49.955258
-47.591584
-50.107631
-38.120322
-42.553827
-45.452827
-41.609616
-37.368340
-42.241799
-53.744867

It seems there is some correlation between them (e.g., their trends are identical). I want to know how to convert RMS level to amplitude so that the waveforms of the recording and the audio playback look similar.

Are you sure you can’t get amplitude values from an audio file for playback? How else would you be able to play that file? FYI, the RMS values you show are in log scale (most probably dBFS)

The results for lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level are in dB full scale.  0 would be full scale (highest value,) negative numbers are lower levels (more negative number is lower level.)
You can read more about lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level here.
The same page also mentions "Max_level" which would be the maximum value of the samples in the specified sampling period.  I think it is the absolute maximum, but the page doesn't say specifically what it is.  Try it and see.
You can't really get the peak from the RMS value.  There could be twenty samples all with the same value, or there could be 19 samples with the same value and one sample with a much higher value - both sets could give the same RMS value.
You should switch to the "Max_level" value, scaling it a bit if needed.

RMS dBFS is calculated by calculating the RMS value of all the samples in a segment, then converting that to a fraction of the full scale.  That fraction is then converted to a decibel representation.

Calculate the RMS value (sum the square of all values in a length of time, divide by the number of samples, take the square root.)
Divide the RMS value by the maximum value for the sample representation you are using.  For 16 bit binary, that would be 32767.  For floating point, that would be 1.
Convert to dBFS: $20 \times log_{10}\frac{RMS}{FS}$


Ohhhhhhhhhh, although the output of Max_level and the Amplitude of mediaRecorder still differ slightly, they are now very close. I think maybe I can directly use them after adjusting the data slightly.
